# SetInterval - problemas

Tags: setinterval

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio que estoy desarrollando , la idea es que cambie de color uno de los imputs tras un numero generado aleatoriamente con la funcion anterior,
el problema es que cuando se lanza el setInterval me devuelve el siguiente error :
Uncaught ReferenceError: brown is not defined
alguien podria ayudarme para saber que estoy haciendo mal , gracias

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title><strong>Whack a Mole</strong></title>
  <h1>
    <p><strong>Whack a Mole</strong></p>
  </h1>
  <div><input type="hole_0" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_1" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_2" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_3" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_4" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_5" name="" class="hole"></div>
</head>

<body>
  <script>




    
    var aleatorio = () => { return Math.round(Math.random() * div.length )}
    
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('hole');
    


   

    setInterval(div[aleatorio()].style.backgroundColor ="brown",1000) ;
        
      

    
    

    
</script>
</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: setInterval=()=>div[aleatorio()].style.backgroundColor ="brown",1000 ; asi no devuelve nada y con {} tampoco , lo del math fue un fallo al copiarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `setInterval` recibe un callback (una función) como primer argumento. Por favor, cambia `div[aleatorio()].style.backgroundColor ="brown"` por:

```
() => div[aleatorio()].style.backgroundColor ="brown".
```

Te adjunto tu código corregido:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title><strong>Whack a Mole</strong></title>
  <h1>
    <p><strong>Whack a Mole</strong></p>
  </h1>
  <div><input type="hole_0" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_1" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_2" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_3" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_4" name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input type="hole_5" name="" class="hole"></div>
</head>

<body>
  <script> 
    var aleatorio = () => { return Math.round(Math.random() * div.length )}
    
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('hole');
   
    setInterval(() => div[aleatorio()].style.backgroundColor ="brown",1000) ;
        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: disculpa , me comi un parentesis , llevo muy pocas horas de java  y todo el dia con esto , muchisimas gracias

Answer (score -1):

```
introducir el código aquí
    var aleatorio = () => { return Math.round(Math.random() * div.length )}

    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('hole');

    setInterval(div[aleatorio()].style.backgroundColor("brown"), 1000) ;
```

**así como accedes a los input por sus clases así mismo asignas valores**